# Limits for auth\access token request in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

Do we have any throttling\limits for request of access token for 1 Application in Azure Active Directory? I found unofficial limitations: 200 calls from 1 user for 30 seconds. This is true?

Answer (score 0):

*Shortly Yes you are right!*

There is a concurrent API calling limits but what exactly the count it has not specified officially. If you refer this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-throttling#what-is-throttling) you would know.

Its calls [`Throttling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-throttling#what-is-throttling). When Throttling happens you would encounter `429 error code` for that. You could check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-error-codes-and-error-handling) See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Best Practice:**

Officially suggested following way to handle request limit:

1. Reduce the number of operations per request.
2. Reduce the frequency of calls.
3. Avoid immediate retries, because all requests accrue against your
   usage limits

For more details you could [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#best-practices-to-handle-throttling).

**Note:**   Calling limit also specifically doesn't specified on [Azure AD service limits and restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-service-limits-restrictions)